# reset cell values based on values in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame which resembles the table given below.

```
  sponbrand aidbrand
1      <NA>     LAYS
2      <NA>     LAYS
3      <NA>     <NA>
4      <NA>     LAYS
5      LAYS     LAYS
6      <NA>     <NA>
```

The reproducible format is as follows:

```
structure(list(sponbrand = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "LAYS", NA), aidbrand = c("LAYS", 
"LAYS", NA, "LAYS", "LAYS", NA)), .Names = c("sponbrand", 
"aidbrand"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to set the following:

If I have a brand in sponbrand I am trying to set the corresponding row in aidbrand as NA.  In the above example, row number 5, has Lays in it in the column sponbrand.  I have Lays in aidbrand column too in row number 5, which I want to set to NA while retaining the rest of the brands in aid brand.  The desired output is as follows:

```
  sponbrand aidbrand
1      <NA>     LAYS
2      <NA>     LAYS
3      <NA>     <NA>
4      <NA>     LAYS
5      LAYS     NA ---->> This is the row I want to reset, while retaining the rest.
6      <NA>     <NA>
```

I have used the following code: cc is my df:

```
if("aidbrand" %in% colnames(cc)){cc$aidbrand <- ifelse(cc$sponbrand == "LAYERR", NA, cc$aidbrand)}
```

This code works perfectly when I have cells without NA's in sponbrand.  However with the current data set this code sets every cell in aidbrand as NA, whereas I want to retain the brands that already exists in aidbrand column.

Comment: `if("aidbrand" %in% colnames(cc)){cc$aidbrand <- ifelse(cc$sponbrand == "LAYS" & !is.na(cc$sponbrand), NA, cc$aidbrand)}` Add another na condition check in the `ifelse`. Since `NA == ...` returns `NA` and `ifelse(NA, ..., ...)` also returns `NA`. However, `NA & FALSE` returns FALSE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're after? I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be

```
#Recreate the dataset
data<-data.frame(sponbrand = as.character(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "LAYS", NA)),
                 aidbrand = as.character(c("LAYS", "LAYS", NA, "LAYS", "LAYS", NA)))
data$aidbrand<-ifelse(!is.na(data$sponbrand),as.character(NA),as.character(data$aidbrand))
data
```

returns:

```
  sponbrand aidbrand
1      <NA>     LAYS
2      <NA>     LAYS
3      <NA>     <NA>
4      <NA>     LAYS
5      LAYS     <NA>
6      <NA>     <NA>
```

Comment: ...this works....I missed passing the as.character(NA) ...since my original variables were factors and I converted them to character , I thought I my code would work...Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
setDT(df)
df[!is.na(sponbrand), aidbrand := NA]
```

Using base R

```
df[!is.na(df$sponbrand), ]$aidbrand <- NA
```

Comment: @snoram...thank u...your code works too.  I don't know the data table option.

Comment: data.table (package) should be much faster when dealing with a very big dataset.